# OSX, Bash date: Show milliseconds/nanoseconds

Tags: macos, bash, date

How do I print the nanoseconds/milliseconds in bash's `date` command in OSX?

[From bash date man page](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?date):

```
%N     nanoseconds (000000000..999999999)
```

On Debian:

```
$ date +%N
028481864
```

But on OSX shell, I get:

```
[$] date +%N
N
```

Comment: It is not possible with the built-in `date`.

Comment: It is a duplicate, and I should just use `gdate`. Thanks.

Comment: ...that said, a high-precision `date` in shell is kinda' silly, because the overhead of starting up an external `date` command is so large that by the time it's printed, it's no longer the time when the request was made. Makes much more sense to, say, pipe output from a shell script through a long-running program that adds timestamps; rather than starting up a new program to just calculate a single timestamp, and start it again whenever you want another one.

Comment: (Very new versions of bash have a lower-overhead way of printing dates in `printf '%(...)T'`; however, that one doesn't support nanoseconds either).